# How can i add a linebreak with javascript at a json file

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

How can i add here now a line break??? i want to see the reports better and not only in one line because its unreadable so can someone help me?

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const ms = require("ms");
let bugreport = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./bugreports.json", "utf8"));
let bugreportlineid = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./bugreports.json", "utf8"));

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
let bugReason = args.join(" ");
let bugID = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1337 / 3 * 1337)
let bugReporter = message.author.tag;

if(!bugreport[bugID]) bugreport[bugID] = {
    BugID: bugID,
    User: bugReporter,
    Bugreport: bugReason
  };

fs.writeFile("./bugreports.json",  JSON.stringify(bugreport), (err) => {
    if(err) console.log(err)
});

message.channel.send(`Bugreport with the ID: ${bugID} sucessfully sended!`)
}

module.exports.help = {
name: "bugreport"
}
```

Comment: `stackoverflow dont detects the code.` wrong. Please read [ask]...

Comment: Please don't expect us to go out and debug your live website. Post the relevant code, right here in your question.

Comment: And it makes no sense to invalidate the json by writing it seperated by newlines into a file. Use an array of objects instead.

Comment: it still dont detects. i made everything what stackflow told me...

Comment: Click the "edit" link in your question and add the code you are working with. Then, highlight that code and on the toolbar, click the `{}` button to format the text as code. Stack Overflow isn't going to prevent you from doing that.

Comment: done can you help now?

Comment: `fs.writeFile("./bugreports.json",  JSON.stringify(bugreport) + "\n", (err) => {`

Comment: Scott Marcus this don't works :/

Comment: try `\r\n` OR `<br>` instead of just `\n`.

Answer (score 4):

If what you want is to pretty print the JSON output use the `space` parameter to [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
fs.writeFile("./bugreports.json",  JSON.stringify(bugreport, null, 2), (err) => {
    if(err) console.log(err)
});
```